# Map in a map function over another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, which in turn can contain arrays. How can I iterate over the inner array within a map? If I try like this, I'll get one

> TypeError: postData.to_json.map is not a function

```
return (
<div className="App">
  {daten.length > 0 &&
    daten.map((postData) => (
      <>
        <h3 key={postData.id}>ID: {postData.id}</h3>

        {postData.to_json.map((data) => (
          <>
            <h3 key={data}>INFO: {data}</h3>
          </>
        ))}
      </>
    ))}
</div>
);
```

My data looks like this

[image]

Comment: The `"..."` indicate that the value of `to_json` is not an array but a string containing JSON. You have to parse it before you can operate on it. Better though: If you control the data generation side, make sure you are not double encoding your data. Only the top level value should be encoded as JSON. If you do that then `postData.to_json.map(...)` will work as expected.

Comment: try changing ```postData.to_json.map((data) => (``` to ```JSON.parse(postData.to_json).map((data) => (```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `to_json` (which is typeof string, not an array) to an array object by:

`{ JSON.parse(postData.to_json).map((data) => ( ... ) }`

Answer (score 0):

change `postData.to_json.map` to `JSON.parse(posData.to_json).map`